# ISE Design Suite 14.7: ISE® Spartan®-6 Virtual Machine (VM) for Windows 10

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, xilinx-ise, spartan

I installed Xilinx ISE 14.7 on Windows 10. When I try to open Project Navigator it opens in a Linux Virtual Machine (VM). It means Xilinx setup installs a VM environment in windows 10.

Is it possible to install ISE Design Suit in windows 10 instead of VM environment.

Answer (score 1):

before we look into the details ... it is important to know that the Spartan 3 or 6 or the ISE development is all history/legacy for Xilinx now ... they still have it on their website for download - but don't actively maintain any of these any more.

There are two versions of ISE14.7 for download at Xilinx

1.) the native windows version - which requires the renaming of dlls as described by @Paebbels - please note that the renaming is required in multiple directories - not just one - and files just need to be renamed - no need to download files from somewhere else

2.) The ISE 14.7 for Windows 10 is - funny - actually a Oracle Linux 6 in a Virtualbox 5 - 
who ever built this has spent lots of effort to make it close to perfect - correct desktop icons in Win and Linux, correct VID/PID setting for the USB programming devices etc. shared folders etc

There is couple of things you should know about these two "twins":

a.) the virtualbox version doesn't run on Win10 with HyperV activated - there is a workaround to make Win10 dualboot with and without hyper-v.

b.) the virtualbox version runs on OSX as well (with Virtualbox installed there) whereas there was never an official ISE Version for OSX / MacOS - but you need to run the installation after download on a Windows machine first - and then transfer the virtualdisk to OSX -

c.) the virtualbox ISE for WIn10 is made for Spartan6 only - it looks like there are Spartan3 files, too, but if you start making a project then you will see lots of files are missing for Spartan3 - but you can create a tar file  from ISE_DS/ISE/spartan3* from the native package and restore it in the virtualbox - and Xilinx said that the virtualbox has some Spartan6 files which the native package doesn't have - same here - use tar to transfer between environments -

d.) unfortunately Oracle Linux 6 has some older tools such as gcc, binutils etc - in most cases that does not matter - but some FPGA projects like Walter's PDP11/70 https://github.com/wfjm/w11 require uptodate tools - in this case check out the Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS 6 to 7 inplace upgrade path - the Xilinx license which comes with the virtualbox is tied to the ethernet address - whereas for the native version we need to get a license at Xilinx website with your personal log in

e.) Some people have problems on Win10 with the programming devices (driver not working), depending on your hardware Digilent Adept might be an alternative

f.) the virtual box has host-only network after install - but you can easily change settings to share host's network connection and reach the internet, e.g. to clone from github or get updates

I hope this helps a bit for orientation - after transferring the missing Spartan3 files from the native package into my virtual box I run 97% of my projects on Win10 or OSX using the virtualbox ISE - which I upgraded to OL 7.6 (YMMV)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can still install XilinX ISE 14.7 natively on Windows 10, but it needs a special trick.

The used [SmartHeap](http://microquill.com/smartheap/) implementation in ISE is either buggy or not compatible with Windows 10 anymore. You need to switch to the non-SmartHeap (NOSH) version.

Here are the steps:

1. Close all Xilinx ISE tools if open or running in the background as zombie processes.
2. Search for `libPortability.dll` (this is the SmartHeap version) in all subdirectories of `C:\Xilinx\14.7\`
3. Rename all instances of `libPortability.dll` to `libPortability.dll.old`.
4. Look for `libPortabilityNOSH.dll` in `C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\lib\nt64`.
5. Copy `libPortabilityNOSH.dll` and rename it to `libPortability.dll`.
6. Also copy the copied and renamed file from step 5 to all directories, that contain a `libPortability.dll.old` (see step 2 and 3).

If you miss one directory, you might be able to start ISE Project Navigator, but XST or PlanAhead might still crash.

Comment: I got same issue. But I cound not find the libPortability.dll library